# Reduce time of for loop

Tags: c++

In my code below. I used a chrono high resolution timer to measure the completion time of **for loop**. This for loop is an important part of my program and I am trying to optimize it. The thing I noticed is that the code line below results in increase in time

```
 buffer[ Bcount]=NextState_chunk1;
```

whereas if I replace this line with

```
buffer[ Bcount]=500;
```

time is reduced to great level

**Full Code:**

```
int NextState_chunk1=0;

for( counter1=0; counter1< sizeof(chunk1); ++counter1)
{

    IndexEntries &data=IndexTable[chunk1[counter1]][chunk1[counter1+1]];
    DoubleTableEntries &GetValue=NewDoubleTable[NextState_chunk1][data.index]; 
    NextState_chunk1= GetValue.Next_State;
    ++Bcount;
    buffer[ Bcount]=NextState_chunk1;
    ++counter1;
}
```

Please point out why is this happening and how can I avoid this problem?

Note: I just replaced the 2nd last line of code only . I did not remove the code lines to measure value of next_state_chunk1.

Comment: You realise you're using `NextState_chunk1` before it it initialized? That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza edited my code. Problem is still the same.

Comment: Is it faster with optimizations off? My guess is the compiler doesn't bother calculating unused values, or can do it faster with a constant value. It seems like your question is irrelevant, since what you're comparing to doesn't achieve your goal.

Comment: If you skip the calculation of `NextState_chunk1` the compiler can wipe out almost all the sentences of the loop (the first three, which i suppose is the core of your algorithm). I'd say you are setting an unrealistic measure of efficiency :)

Comment: @perencia I calculated nextState_chunk1 exactly as mentioned in code , only replaced the 2nd last line of code.

Comment: @Zara so you are not using it and the compiler can erase it and with it, all of the calculations that lead to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to venture a guess that when you have

```
buffer[ Bcount]=500;
```

in the for loop, the compiler is able to optimize away the unnecessary parts of the loop. It gets simplified to:

```
for( counter1=0; counter1< sizeof(chunk1); ++counter1)
{
    ++Bcount;
    buffer[ Bcount]=500;
    ++counter1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple, your modification reduces your loop to (disregarding **Undefined Behavior**):

```
for( counter1=0; counter1< sizeof(chunk1); counter1 += 2)
    Buffer[++Bcount] = 500;
NextStateChunk1 = ... complicated expression ...
```

There's an excellent chance the compiler can condense that even further due to how the variables are set / used previously / further on.